# Matlab add string variable as column in table

Tags: matlab, yolov4, matlab-table

I'm trying to use YOLOv4 in MATLAB R2022b to carry out detections on all images in a directory, and append results to a text file.

I can append just the detection results to each line, but when I try to add the filename I get this error:

> You might have intended to create a one-row table with the character vector '000001.jpg' as one of its variables. To store text data in a table, use a string array or a cell array of character vectors rather than character arrays. Alternatively, create a cell array with one row, and convert that to a table using CELL2TABLE.

I understand that the filename is a string, and the values returned by YOLO are a categorical array, but I don't understand the most efficient way to deal with this.

```matlab
filesDir = dir("/home/ADL-Rundle-1/img1/");
for k=1:length(filesDir)
   baseFileName=filesDir(k).name
   fullFileName = fullfile(filesDir(k).folder, baseFileName);
   if isfile(fullFileName)
        img = imread(fullFileName);
        [bboxes,scores,labels] = detect(detector,img);
        T = table(baseFileName, labels, bboxes, scores); 
        writetable(T,'/home/tableDataPreTrained.txt','WriteMode','Append','WriteVariableNames',0);
   end
end
```

The format of results from YOLO is
[image]

And I'd like a file with

000001.jpg, 1547.3, 347.35, 355.64, 716.94, 0.99729

000001.jpg, 717.81, 370.64, 76.444, 108.92, 0.61191

000002.jpg, 1,      569.5, 246.49, 147.25,0.56831

Answer (score 0):

`baseFileName` is a char vector.

The error message is telling you to use a cell array of char vectors:

```matlab
T = table({baseFileName}, labels, bboxes, scores);
```

or a string array:

```matlab
T = table(string(baseFileName), labels, bboxes, scores);
```

I would use the string array, it's the more modern MATLAB, and the table looks prettier when displayed. But both accomplish the same thing.

Given that `labels` and the other two variables have multiple rows, you need to replicate the file name that number of times:

```matlab
frame = repmat(string(baseFileName), size(labels,1), 1);
T = table(frame, labels, bboxes, scores);
```

Comment: Thanks Cris, but both of those give the error: using table All table variables must have the same number of rows. Not sure if it helps, I'll add the table format with the outputs from YOLO to my original post.

Comment: Sorry, just saw your reply.  Yes I'd like the filename added to all the rows, so that I can use it later to track movement of persons through each frame.

Comment: @EMC You can do that by replicating the file name for each row, see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Cris, both for the speedy reply, and for the fact that it's working perfectly now!

Comment: A handy syntax if you've already constructed the variable using `table()` (without that variable) is you can populate a whole new column with a char using `T.frame(:) = {baseFileName};`